# Sort array - digits, special chars, letters

Tags: php, sorting

i have array of digits, special chars and letters. How i can sort it that first walked digist, then special chars and leters.

```
$c64 = str_split(
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
);
```

I trying doing like this

```
array_multisort($l64, SORT_DESC);
```

But it return special chars, digits and letters

Comment: i guess you have to write a function for that yourself and use uasort http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: So you are using `SORT_DESC` and actually write *but*? That makes no sense. The documentation of `SORT_DESC` was not announced to work the way you're using it, so how could you overlook that if I may ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing can be implemented in very "clever" ways, so I couldn't resist:

```
$c64 = str_split(
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'
);

$sortValue = function($char) {
    return !ctype_digit($char) << 9 | !ctype_punct($char) << 8 | ord($char);
}

$sortFunction = function($x, $y) use ($sortValue) {
    return $sortValue($x) - $sortValue($y);
};

usort($c64, $sortFunction);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/i3tCsr)**.

**How it works**

I 'm taking advantage of the fact that `ord` returns the ordinal value of a character, which is both what plain `sort` uses to sort the input *and also* constrained to the range [0, 255] -- i.e. it uses no more than 8 bits for its value.

What this code is doing is taking the return value of `ord` (remember: that's how the default `sort` works) and augmenting it with two extra bits of information: the MSB represents "is this character *not* a digit?" and the LSB represents "is this character *not* punctuation?".

These bits are ORed together with the ordinal value, producing 10-bit quantities that look like this:

```
Bit#    10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
         ^  ^  ^                       ^
         |  |  \-----------+-----------/   
         |  |              \------------- ord
         |  \---------------------------- "not punctuation" bit
         \------------------------------- "not digit" bit
```

What happens when you treat these values as integers? Clearly values that correspond to non-digits are going to be larger than any others, and similarly values that correspond to non-punctuation are going to be larger than letters and such.

So by using the result of `$x - $y` to determine which item is larger we are in effect making digits be considered smaller than everything else and punctuation larger than digits but smaller than non-digits. This makes `sort` put digits first, then punctuation, then everything else when it makes an ascending sort.

Finally, it is very significant that the value of `ord` takes part in the comparison: for elements in the same class (e.g. digits) we want their sort order to be the same as the order a plain `sort` would produce.

Comment: + Interesting .... a bitwise approach

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($c64, function($a, $b){
    $aord = (is_numeric($a)) ? $a : ord($a);
    $bord = (is_numeric($b)) ? $b : ord($b);
    if ($aord == $bord) return 0;
    return ($aord < $bord) ? -1 : 1;
});
```