# How to sort an array in php by this order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array based on these rules :
Case insensitive , alphabetical characters first, numerics second and other characters last based on ASCII order. 
This array : `"toto" "tutu" "4234" "_hop XXX" "##" "1948372" "AhAhAh"` should result in :

```
AhAhAh
toto
tutu
XXX
1948372
4234
#
_hop
```

Comment: You can define your own order using `usort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: this might help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473879/sort-array-digits-special-chars-letters

Comment: Is it fit in any existing algorithm?? If not then make it own using `usort`.    The usort() function sorts an array using a user-defined comparison function.